# Size button margin different between preview and window display

Tags: c#, wpf, button, margin

I have a window with some control like this:

[image: Preview display]

But when i launch my button have a padding like this:

[image: final display]

this is an part of my code:

```
<Grid>
    <Rectangle Fill="Gray"/>
    <Button Width="60" Height="60" Margin="117,10,117,201">up</Button>
    <Button Width="60" Height="60" Margin="57,70,177,141">left</Button>
    <Button Width="60" Height="60" Margin="117,70,117,141">reset</Button>
    <Button Width="60" Height="60" Margin="177,70,57,141">right</Button>
    <Button Width="60" Height="60" Margin="117,130,117,81">drown</Button>

    <Button Width="60" Height="60" Margin="12,201,222,10">load</Button>
    <Button Width="60" Height="60" Margin="84,201,150,10">play</Button>
    <Button Width="60" Height="60" Margin="156,201,78,10">previous move </Button>
    <Button Width="60" Height="60" Margin="222,201,12,10">next move</Button>
</Grid>
```

Can some one can say me why i have this padding and who i can remove it ?

I have try to put a padding negative in my button but it's the same display

Comment: It is working fine at my end. It shows like in the first image only.

Comment: maybe because windows 8 ?

Comment: Maybe. I hope the above code is placed in a window and not a user control? Even placing it in a user control and then into a window works fine for me. Try setting this for buttons and check `Width="Auto" Height="Auto"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a easy way to solve my problem.

I have create a grid for define size of all my element:

```
<Grid Margin="55,10,50,75">
 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <RowDefinition Height="60" />
  <RowDefinition Height="60" />
  <RowDefinition Height="60" />
 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
  <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
  <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

 <Button Name="UpButton" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
 <Button Name="LeftButton" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
 <Button Name="ResetButton" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
 <Button Name="RightButton" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"/>
 <Button Name="DownButton" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```

And now i have this in display with some add

[image: Final Result]

Answer (score 0):

I'm sensing that you are loading style resource to the application at Runtime that contains **default style for the `Button` applied to all `Button` control**

Something like this.

```
<Style TargetType="Button">            
   <Setter Property="Padding" Value="20,10,0,0" />
</Style>
```

To overcome this, you have two ways,

- Find the style resource, either remove or set the `x:key` attribute for the style.
- Set `Padding = 0` locally for each `Button` or in the `Resources` of `Grid` the will give precedence as mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx)

Hope that helps :)